# Create *.txt file through ADB with specific content inside

Tags: android, adb

I'd like to create a *.txt file inside my Android device through ADB and have a specific text inside.
Is there any easy way of doing this?
I know it can be pushed but I don't want to use this feature and generate it directly on the target.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
adb shell
echo "Hello world" > /sdcard/file.txt
```

Comment: hi want to write the data to the file.txt which is in android clipboard .. how to do that? we can paste the clipboard data to any text field like message using the "adb shell input keyevent 279" command. but how to write it in the text file?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Android OS is based on Linux OS, so use any Linux command after `adb shell` to create file like:

```
echo "HelloWorld" > test.txt
```

or

```
touch test.txt
```

**Note** touch will create test.txt empty

Answer (score -3):

You can try by creating file

```
$ adb shell touch data.txt
```

and than write data into it

```
$ adb shell echo "Hello World" > data.txt
```

Comment: That's not valid answer. You need to run adb shell. Have you even checked that you are posting?

Comment: The `$ adb shell touch data.txt` actually works, but `$ adb shell echo "Hello World" > data.txt` failed with "No such file" error, though I had verified its creation with the right path.

Comment: You don't need to create the file but you have to surround the commands with single quotes 

`$ adb shell 'echo "Hello World" > /scard/Android/data/myFile.txt'`